# Plot mean curve of several curves with different amount of datapoints in the same range

Tags: python

I have datasets containing x- and y-values. The minimum and maximum x-values are always the same (let's say x_min is always 0 and x_max is always 4). But the amount of x-values in that range of 0 to 4 is different for every dataset. Sometimes there are 400 datapoints in this range, sometimes 600 datapoints. Also, the x-values themselves are never exactly the same.

Here is an example of how the datasets look like:

`dataset_1:`

```
    x1            y1
    ---------     ---------
    0.0000        0.5686
    0.1258        1.2568
    0.9899        2.3583
    0.8789        3.5455
    1.5686        4.2588
    ...           ...
    3.4686        6.2355
    3.9899        7.3535
    4.0000        9.9855
```

`dataset_2:`

```
    x2            y2
    ---------     ---------
    0.0000        0.4275
    0.4898        1.5577
    0.7556        2.9544
    1.3257        3.1275
    1.9755        4.7577
    ...           ...
    2.2552        6.9544
    3.2488        7.4657
    4.0000        9.1758
```

I would like to plot those different datasets together with a **mean curve of those datasets**.
Is there a way to do this in Python?